# nodejs v0.10.15 windows 8 - slow start

Tags: windows, performance, node.js

I have the same version on Ubuntu and Windows 8 - v0.10.15, same script with express.js.
Nodejs on ubuntu restarts immediately (when i use supervisor, or just run debug from phpstorm). But in windows 8 it's writes to the console that server is started, but when i check it in browser page loaded with a delay.

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using Chrome 28.0.1500.95 m., but page loaded with a delay in all browsers. (firefox, opera, ie)

Comment: Same problem with v0.10.17. It makes debugging unreal